# scale UITextView height as iphone SMS-app

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uitextview

To start with I am a very unexperienced IOS developer both in terms of this being my frist app and also being my frist time developing in Objective C. I am now trying to develop a chat function like the native one in the iPhone SMS-app. I have followed this guide: https://github.com/HansPinckaers/GrowingTextView how to create a TextView that scale's height depending on the amount of text.

Ofcourse I want to integrate this with my existing UIViewController built in storyboard instead of customizing a new one by code like being done in this tutorial: https://github.com/HansPinckaers/GrowingTextView/blob/master/example/Classes/GrowingTextViewExampleViewController.m

```
- (void)loadView {
self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:219.0f/255.0f green:226.0f/255.0f blue:237.0f/255.0f alpha:1];
.......................................... etc

[self.view addSubview:containerView];
...........................................etc
}
```

And now comes the funny part, if I wanna replace self.view code above to be self.view = my viewController from storyboard what shall I type? Or should I wash my brain and totaly rethink and do this in another way? Thanx in advance

Comment: has your existing view controller a .xib file? yes the specify that in  initWithNib

Comment: There is a Library available which may be helpful: http://alexbarinov.github.com/UIBubbleTableView/